# Bootstrap Modal overlapping in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I have a very wiered problem. Might be something stupid I have got on my HTML Code. I have an HTML page which has two bootstrap modal divs. I will use jQuery to call up these modals. When I include one it works fine, but when I have more than one on my page, its DOM is overlapping. Please help.

The two modal divs are in the body of my html tag as :

```
    <!-- Modal : Add/Edit Home Phone -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="AddHomePhoneModel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="HomePhoneModelLabel">
      <div id="AddHomePhoneModalDialog" class="modal-dialog" >
        <div class="modal-content" id="AddHomePhoneModalContent">
          <div class="modal-header" id="AddHomePhoneModalHeader">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add / Edit Home Phone</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body" id="AddHomePhoneModalBody">               
                <form class="form-horizontal" id="AddHomePhoneModelForm" role="form">

                  <div class="divToUpdate" />

                  <input type="hidden" name="phone_number_id" class="PhoneNumberId"/>
                  <input type="hidden" name="HomeContact_TimeStampID" class="HomeContact_TimeStampID"/>
                  <input type="hidden" name="hps_modified_by" class="hps_modified_by" />

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="home_phone_country" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Country Code</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                      <input type="text" name="home_phone_country" class="form-control" id="home_phone_country" >
                    </div>
                    <small class="help-block with-errors"></small>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="home_phone_number" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Phone Number</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                      <input type="text" name="home_phone_number" class="form-control" id="home_phone_number" >
                    </div>
                    <small class="help-block with-errors"></small>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="home_phone_status" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Can contact?</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-6" id="home_phone_status">
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                          <input type="radio" name="home_phone_status" id="HPSY" value="Y"> Yes
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                          <input type="radio" name="home_phone_status" id="HPSN" value="N"> No
                        </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="home_phone_sms_status" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Contact via SMS?</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-6" id="home_phone_sms_status">
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                          <input type="radio" name="home_phone_sms_status" id="HPSSY" value="Y" required> Yes
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                          <input type="radio" name="home_phone_sms_status" id="HPSSN" value="N" required> No
                        </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="home_preferred_contact_flag" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Preferred Contact?</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-6" id="home_preferred_contact_flag">
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                          <input type="radio" name="home_preferred_contact_flag" id="HPCFY" value="Y" required> Yes
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                          <input type="radio" name="home_preferred_contact_flag" id="HPCFN" value="N" required> No
                        </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </form>
                <div class="bg-danger" id="AddHomePhoneMsg"/>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer" id="AddHomePhoneModalFooter">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button id="AddNewHomePhoneBtn" data-loading-text="Saving..." type="button" onclick="AddNewHomePhoneHbase();" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  

  <!-- Modal : Add/Edit Email -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="AddEmailModel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="EmailModelLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" id="AddEmailModalDialog">
        <div class="modal-content" id="AddEmailModalContent">
          <div class="modal-header" id="AddEmailModalHeader">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add / Edit Email</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body" id="AddEmailModalBody">               
                <form class="form-horizontal" id="AddEmailModelForm" role="form">

                  <div class="divToUpdate" />

                  <input type="hidden" name="phone_number_id" class="PhoneNumberId"/>
                  <input type="hidden" name="Email_TimeStampID" class="Email_TimeStampID"/>
                  <input type="hidden" name="es_modified_by" class="es_modified_by" />

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" >
                    </div>
                    <small class="help-block with-errors"></small>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email_type" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Email Type</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-6" id="email_type">
                        <select class="form-control" name="email_type">
                          <option value="Personal">Personal</option>
                          <option value="Office">Office</option>
                          <option value="Home">Home</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="preferred_email_status" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Preferred Email</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-6" id="preferred_email_status">
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                          <input type="radio" name="preferred_email_status" id="PrefEmailY" value="Y"> Yes
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                          <input type="radio" name="preferred_email_status" id="PrefEmailN" value="N"> No
                        </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email_status" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Active Email</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-6" id="email_status">
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                          <input type="radio" name="email_status" id="EmailStatY" value="Y" required> Yes
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                          <input type="radio" name="email_status" id="EmailStatN" value="N" required> No
                        </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
                <div class="bg-danger" id="AddEmailMsg"/>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer" id="AddEmailModalFooter">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button id="AddNewEmailBtn" data-loading-text="Saving..." type="button" onclick="AddNewEmailHbase();" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

But when I view it using a browser both the modals are appearing as nested ones like :

[image]

Any help is appreaciated. I will have a couple of more models in the same page, and will want to retain it in the same page.

Comment: You cannot show two modals at the same time with bootstrap .. not out of the box anyways .. but seems to remember some plugin which might do the trick

Comment: Confused .. Are you trying to open (SHOW) two modals at the same time ? or ?

Comment: Yes you can you just have to change the IDs and names

Comment: @AnthonyBroadbent: You cannot SHOW 2 modals at the same time with bootstrap out of the box. You are right, that you can have as many modals defined .. I was a bit confused by the question and the problem ..

Comment: Ah sorry I read that wrong, no you cannot show 2 modals .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you havent closed your modals correctly. Try this:

```
        <!-- Modal : Add/Edit Home Phone -->
<div class="modal fade" id="AddHomePhoneModel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="HomePhoneModelLabel">
    <div id="AddHomePhoneModalDialog" class="modal-dialog" >
        <div class="modal-content" id="AddHomePhoneModalContent">
            <div class="modal-header" id="AddHomePhoneModalHeader">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add / Edit Home Phone</h4>
            </div>
            <form class="form-horizontal" id="AddHomePhoneModelForm" role="form">
                <div class="modal-body" id="AddHomePhoneModalBody">
                    <div class="divToUpdate" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="phone_number_id" class="PhoneNumberId"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="HomeContact_TimeStampID" class="HomeContact_TimeStampID"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="hps_modified_by" class="hps_modified_by" />
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="home_phone_country" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Country Code</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <input type="text" name="home_phone_country" class="form-control" id="home_phone_country" >
                            </div>
                            <small class="help-block with-errors"></small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="home_phone_number" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Phone Number</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <input type="text" name="home_phone_number" class="form-control" id="home_phone_number" >
                            </div>
                            <small class="help-block with-errors"></small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="home_phone_status" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Can contact?</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-6" id="home_phone_status">
                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" name="home_phone_status" id="HPSY" value="Y"> Yes
                                </label>
                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" name="home_phone_status" id="HPSN" value="N"> No
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="home_phone_sms_status" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Contact via SMS?</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-6" id="home_phone_sms_status">
                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" name="home_phone_sms_status" id="HPSSY" value="Y" required> Yes
                                </label>
                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" name="home_phone_sms_status" id="HPSSN" value="N" required> No
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="home_preferred_contact_flag" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Preferred Contact?</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-6" id="home_preferred_contact_flag">
                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" name="home_preferred_contact_flag" id="HPCFY" value="Y" required> Yes
                                </label>
                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" name="home_preferred_contact_flag" id="HPCFN" value="N" required> No
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bg-danger" id="AddHomePhoneMsg"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer" id="AddHomePhoneModalFooter">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button id="AddNewHomePhoneBtn" data-loading-text="Saving..." type="button" onclick="AddNewHomePhoneHbase();" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal : Add/Edit Email -->
<div class="modal fade" id="AddEmailModel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="EmailModelLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" id="AddEmailModalDialog">
        <div class="modal-content" id="AddEmailModalContent">
            <div class="modal-header" id="AddEmailModalHeader">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add / Edit Email</h4>
            </div>
            <form class="form-horizontal" id="AddEmailModelForm" role="form">
                <div class="modal-body" id="AddEmailModalBody">

                    <div class="divToUpdate" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="phone_number_id" class="PhoneNumberId"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="Email_TimeStampID" class="Email_TimeStampID"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="es_modified_by" class="es_modified_by" />
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Email</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" >
                            </div>
                            <small class="help-block with-errors"></small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email_type" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Email Type</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-6" id="email_type">
                                <select class="form-control" name="email_type">
                                    <option value="Personal">Personal</option>
                                    <option value="Office">Office</option>
                                    <option value="Home">Home</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="preferred_email_status" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Preferred Email</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-6" id="preferred_email_status">
                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" name="preferred_email_status" id="PrefEmailY" value="Y"> Yes
                                </label>
                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" name="preferred_email_status" id="PrefEmailN" value="N"> No
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email_status" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Active Email</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-6" id="email_status">
                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" name="email_status" id="EmailStatY" value="Y" required> Yes
                                </label>
                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" name="email_status" id="EmailStatN" value="N" required> No
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bg-danger" id="AddEmailMsg"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer" id="AddEmailModalFooter">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button id="AddNewEmailBtn" data-loading-text="Saving..." type="button" onclick="AddNewEmailHbase();" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `modal-body` should be closed before `modal-footer` the answer may resolve the OP's problem but still the closing `</div>` are at wrong place

Comment: Ive also moved the `<form>` tags which should fix the issue.